# Preprocessor Definitions To Identify Debug/Release Mode in VxWorks

Tags: c++, vxworks

Which preprocessor definitions let you identify the build version of a project in VxWorks? I'm looking for something on the lines of _DEBUG (Debug mode)/ _NDEBUG (Release mode) which are used in VC++.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
  string strBuildMode = "Debug";
#else
  string strBuildMode = "Release";
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard macro (also supported by VC++) is `NDEBUG`. It has negative logic: it's *defined* in release builds. The documented function is to turn `assert()` (from `<cassert>`) off.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a switch -DDEBUG in the 'tool flags' options of the build properties for debug mode (along with -g option). The macro can then be used in the program to identify the build mode.